# Is it possible to write an SQL function that outputs JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just had the idea of writing a function in MySQL that I can pass a subquery to for it to output the JSON representation of that subquery.

I have quite a lot of data that I often fetch from MySQL, then convert it to JSON for API output. Could it perhaps be a speed increase to write a MySQL function to do this on the SQL server that just returns the JSON?

My imagination:

```
query('SELECT * FROM people');

// Output:
// +----+--------+-----+
// | id | name   | Age |
// +----+--------+-----+
// |  1 | Molly  | 24  |
// |  2 | Edward | 28  |
// +----+--------+-----+

query('JSON(SELECT * FROM people)');

// Output:
// [{"id":1,"name":"Molly","Age":24},{"id":2,"name":"Edward","Age":28}]
```

Possible? If yes, any clues to how I can start?

Comment: It is possible but will hardly be any speed increase. Also, for large resultsets, you can hit certain limits like `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` which would prevent the value to be returned. They are not always possible to change on shared hostings etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how data is usually sent from MySQL to a client as a response to a query. Would this perhaps reduce bandwidth if the MySQL host was not local?

Comment: `MySQL`'s binary protocol is denser than character-based `JSON`. Also, you can compress it with `MYSQL_CLIENT_COMPRESS` (should you need it).

Comment: `SELECT '{"id":1}'` No need to thank me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818441/sql-server-select-to-json-function) (SQL Server) on StackOverflow.

You can also see [here](http://embosa.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/oracle-and-json-using-pljson/) for PL/JSON, and [here](http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/sql2json/) for sql2json (PHP).

Answer (score 3):

As of MySQL 5.7 you can output JSON using `JSON_ARRAY` and `JSON_MERGE` among other functions.

It works like so:

```
RETURN JSON_ARRAY('id':1,'name':'Molly','Age':24);
```

You can have multiple documents also:

```
RETURN JSON_MERGE('{"id":1,"name":"Molly","Age":24}', '{"id":2,"name":"Edward","Age":28}');
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about a table with username and email, you can contruct the JSON in following manner in MySQl User defined function.

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT("[",
          GROUP_CONCAT(
               CONCAT("{username:'",username,"'"),
               CONCAT(",email:'",email),"'}")
          )
     ,"]") 
AS json FROM users;
```

A MySQL-query that returns JSON.

```
[
     {username:'mike',email:'mike@mikesplace.com'},
     {username:'jane',email:'jane@bigcompany.com'},
     {username:'stan',email:'stan@stanford.com'}
]
```

There is no inbuilt method that converts result to JSON format, so you have to do yourself in UDF.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Probably it's best to use quotes also for object keys. Otherwise it looks perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in writing SQL to generate JSON, it's just messy and ugly and would be really hard to generalize into an all-purpose function, and it's not really what SQL is designed for; SQL is designed to manage, store and retrieve the records you need and perform calculations on result sets - really fast and on the fly - and not much more.  If you need JSON you have to spit the rows out to a server-side script anyways so you might as well use the scripting language to create JSON  - that's what scripting languages are *for.*

Comment: Interesting emphasis of 'for' at the end there.

Comment: I really think that the question has an - at least - performance related point. Why should I need e.g 100kB data read into DB Server memory, sent over IP and then loaded again in PHP/JS/whatever memory, just to convert them to JSON format, when SQL can do it and probably a lot faster!!

Comment: at this time when tools like graphql gets hyped, this kind of question looks way more relevant — why need a tool to overlays mysql when it can actually do the job by itself ?