# How to convert data to json format in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and want to convert table data into json format. Can I convert it directly through firing query?

Comment: There isn't a SQL Server 2007. But assuming yyyy<2016 then there is no inbuilt functionality to do this.

Comment: No, SQL Server 2008 doesn't have any support for handling JSON directly. SQL Server **2016** will have full support for JSON - until then, you need to do this in your logic layer (in whatever programming language you're comfortable with)

Comment: The logic for doing this is relatively easy.  It is also relatively straightforward to emit json from a client SQL application.  If you MUST do it directly from SQL, you could write a stored procedure or an extended stored procedure written in C/C++ or C# (warning - a lot of shops legislate against this and for good reason).  I think the client program is the way to go and for what it's worth also think that SQL Server is best reserved for data storage, query, and manipulation - not formatting and presentation to the user, which is really the forte of the client program.  Good Luck.

Comment: Clarification: it is the extended stored procedures that is outlawed by many shops. a sproc is a bit more involved though than a client program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT to JSON function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818441/sql-server-select-to-json-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built in support for formatting query results is added in SQL Server 2016 and it will be available in Azure Database.
In older versions you would need to use CLR or some heavy TSQL like:

- [Producing JSON Documents from SQL Server queries via TSQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/)

Answer (score 5):

I have created a stored procedure that can take your table and output JSON. You can find it at

- [GitHub - SQLTableOrViewToJSON](https://github.com/ahliana/SQLTableOrViewToJSON)

Once you run the stored procedure, you can output your table by making a call like the following:

```
EXEC SQLTableOrViewToJSON 'MyTable', 'C:\WhereIStowMyJSON\'
```

Comment: can't make it work with temporal ##tables or TempDB..tables

Answer (score -3):

The above solutions seem unnecessarily complicated; starting with 2008, SQL Server supports the following syntax (answer from [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229433/select-multiple-columns-as-json-in-a-single-query))

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.x FOR JSON AUTO;
```

The above query returns a single JSON-formatted column that looks like this (assuming `dbo.x` contains columns `col1`~`col4`of corresponding types):

```
[{"col1":"val1","col2":"val2","col3":5,"col4":"2019-02-11"}]
```

More details/options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server

Comment: Starting with 2014 according to your own link.

Comment: @AXMIM where do you see 2014?

Comment: There is a version at the top left of the screen. You can't pick any version before 2014. Also, I've tried it and it isn't recognized in 2008R2