# SQL - Query to JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a result from a `select` into `JSON` format, to do this I found the following script

```
select rankName as name
    from tbUserHasRank 
    where userTag = 'test' 
    for json auto
```

however I receive the error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'json'.
```

so... what's incorrect with my syntax I wonder?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Are you using SQL 2016?

Comment: Without being sure I would say, `SQL Server 11.0.2100´ express version

Comment: Michael, this looks like its a feature in 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx

Comment: Yes according to their page it says: SQL Server (starting with 2016)

Comment: I did a google search and it shows its 2012: https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+11.0.2100&oq=SQL+Server+11.0.2100&aqs=chrome..69i57.1536j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: ah, I see. Is there a way to accomplish the same result in `SQL Server 2012`?

Comment: Not easily. Perhaps using C# to shape the data into an object, then serialize to JSON would be easier than writing your own JSON serializer function for SQL data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own SQL query ie

```
select '"name":' + '"' + rankName + '"'
from tbUserHasRank 
where userTag = 'test'
```

Comment: I don't think the OP expects this kind of solution and you might need to escape special characters,

Comment: @C.Champagne yes special characters need to be escaped and formatting needs to done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a [CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx) in C# (or whatever) or you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6818566/1153988) but I am not sure that special characters are correctly escaped.

Comment: C# wouldn't be a good solution as my limitations state that I can only use SQL

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard have you tried the solution given by the second link? It uses xml capabilities of SQL Server.