# Get result of sql query in JSON format via MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2014

I need to get result of sql query in JSON format via MSSQL 2014.
I have wrote this code:

```
SELECT bc.Id, bc.CityName, bc.ProvinceId FROM BusCity AS bc WHERE bc.Country=2 FOR JSON AUTO
```

But I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'JSON'.

Is this possible? How to do this?

Comment: `FOR JSON` is not available with 2014. Here is an answer with an alternative approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818441/sql-server-select-to-json-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You running 2016 or higher?

FOR JSON was introduced then.

Type

```
SELECT @@Version
```

To find out what version you're running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
 Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Yup.  It's not available on your version of SQL.