# SQL DATABSE TO JSON no PHP use

Tags: jquery, sql, json

I am new in development, can anyone tell me, i want to fetch data of employee from sql database and want to show it on website through json and jquery.

can anyone tell me how to convert sql database into json format? please. BUT I DON'T WANT TO USE PHP.

tHANKS

Comment: take a look to [SQL Server SELECT to JSON function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818441/sql-server-select-to-json-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is Oracle and greater that 12.2C you can retrieve using **JSON_OBJECT** function. If you are open to use Python follow the below link to export your SQL table to JSON:

https://anthonydebarros.com/2012/03/11/generate-json-from-sql-using-python/